# Operation Invalid for Compressed Container in GridDB

Tags: griddb

I am performing a data analysis on the factors affecting the fuel prices worldwide. I have created a container and its schema looks as follows:

```js
const conInfo = new griddb.ContainerInfo({
    'name': "globalfluctuationsfuelprices",
    'columnInfoList': [
      ["country", griddb.Type.STRING],
      ["daily oil consumption (barrels)", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
      ["world share", griddb.Type.STRING],
      ["yearly gallons per capita", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
      ["price per gallon (USD)", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
      ["price per liter (USD)", griddb.Type.DOUBLE],
      ["price per liter (PKR)", griddb.Type.DOUBLE]
    ],
    'type': griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, 'rowKey': true
});
```

I wanted to alter `conInfo` by adding another column in the container to add the average monthly change in fuel prices. I tried using the following command:

```sql
ALTER TABLE conInfo ADD COLUMN avg_monthly_change DOUBLE;
```

Unfortunately, I was unable to do so and received the error mentioned below:

```
[Server]: 60086

[Description] (Operation invalid for compressed container)
```

How should I resolve this?